# How to dynamically connect to multiple mongodb databases in NESTJS without creating a new database connection with every request

Tags: typescript, mongodb, nestjs, nest

I would like to ask:
I'm using nest with mongodb as an API for a multi tenanty service, that is, I will have a database in mongodb for each tenant.
I saw in the nest documentation that, in order to have several database connections, we need to do this in app.module:

```
app.module.tsJS

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost/test', {
      connectionName: 'cats',
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost/users', {
      connectionName: 'users',
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

But, assuming that the amount of new databases is dynamic (coming from another database), how could I leave this configuration dynamic? Remembering that I can already make my query of "connectionName" and "connectionString" within a service.

Comment: i an in need for the same exact solution, did you find something ?

Comment: @AissamJadli not yet... :(

and I'm hoping I'll find something like this, I'm sad that currently NEST doesn't have so much material available, nor a strong community... it's a beautiful framework but very little clarity in its features...

Comment: yeah, in the end, i implemented my own repo with these features

Comment: hmm, can you share the solution?  Or is it a private repo?

Comment: @AissamJadli can you please?